# Conditional Formating - multiple cells with different relations

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

So here is what I am looking for:

I want to highlight several cells, such as A1:A5 need to turn red based on a conditional format formula.

The conditional format for A1 would be:

```
=((A1/B1)<C1)
```

If true the cell turns red. Note C1.

The conditional format for A2 would be:

```
=((A2/B2)<C1%)
```

If true the cell turns red. Note it is still C1.

So here is the obvious question; how can I copy and paste this conditional formatting so that C1 does not change so that I can have only 1 rule vs 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot cause a comment to solve the question. So, all credit goes to Scott Craner.

=((A2/B2)< C $1)

At the point in time i asked this, i did not know the function of $. Thank you!